# Multiple Joins with conditions taking too long to execute

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I'm trying to join multiple tables (in different databases) together based on ST_WITHIN. I have greatly simplified my query and database structure for demonstration purposes.

```
remedy=pd.read_sql("""SELECT
                      `t1`.`Code`,
                      `t1`.`price`,
                      `t1`.`Latitude`,
                      `t1`.`Longitude`,
                      `t2`.`tier_name`,
                      `t2`.`tier2_name`,
                      `t3`.`id`
                      FROM `database_2`.`table_2` t2
                      RIGHT JOIN `database_1`.`table_1` t1
                      ON ST_WITHIN(Point(`t1`.`Latitude`, `t1`.`Longitude`), `t2`.`geometry`)
                      AND t1.`Code` != "TEST"

                      LEFT JOIN `database_2`.`table_3` t3
                      ON ST_WITHIN(Point(`t1`.`Latitude`, `t1`.`Longitude`), `t3`.`geometry`)
""", cnx)
```

The thing is this query takes forever to execute and it seems as if my system (running on RHEL Linux with MariaDB) is stuck on the query. I had to manually kill the query since it was just stuck. Is there any other approach or something I am missing which is causing the extensive lag?

Logic of the query: I did a right join on table_1 since I'm only interested in the rows of  table_1. Table_1 is 158,407 rows and I would want my FINAL result to be 158,407 rows. I was able to join two of the tables together based on ST_WITHIN, but when I add a third, it seems that although the query doesn't run into any error, it seems to be stuck.

---

For context, table_1 (158,407 rows) is constructed as follows:

```
          Code  price  Latitude  Longitude  
0         A001   1200     43.65      -79.1
1        A3421    150     40.78      -73.9
2            B    300     42.82      -67.3
3          HCO    450     22.22      -22.2
4         WREA    200     39.80       32.3
```

table_2 (654 rows):

```
          tier_name  tier2_name              geometry  
0          Sample 1    Sample 1  [GEOMETRY - 2.7 KiB] 
1          Sample 2    Sample 2  [GEOMETRY - 2.7 KiB]
2          Sample 3    Sample 3  [GEOMETRY - 2.7 KiB]
3          Sample 4    Sample 4  [GEOMETRY - 2.7 KiB]
4          Sample 5    Sample 5  [GEOMETRY - 2.7 KiB]
...             ...         ...                   ...
```

Table_3 (72 rows):

```
             id             geometry  
0          ID 1  [GEOMETRY - 2.7 KiB] 
1          ID 2  [GEOMETRY - 2.7 KiB]
2          ID 3  [GEOMETRY - 2.7 KiB]
3          ID 4  [GEOMETRY - 2.7 KiB]
4          ID 5  [GEOMETRY - 2.7 KiB]
...         ...                   ...
```

Ideally, I would like my result to look like:

```
          Code  price  Latitude  Longitude  tier_name  tier2_name  id  
0         A001   1200     43.65      -79.1   Sample 5    Sample 5  ID 3   <-- The point (43.65 and -79.1) is in the polygon sample 5
1        A3421    150     40.78      -73.9   Sample 5    Sample 5  ID 3
2            B    300     42.82      -67.3                         ID 1   <-- This point is in none of the polygons of dataframe #2 
3          HCO    450     22.22      -22.2   Sample 2    Sample 2  ID 4
4         WREA    200     39.80       32.3   Sample 3    Sample 3
...        ...    ...       ...        ...        ...        ....
```

Comment: An EXPLAIN would be useful. What indexes have you created?

Comment: Wait what do you mean what indices?

Comment: What indices have you created for the spatial data? The Point stored in table_1 is not stored in a geometry so cannot use a spatial index (I think) but the geometry columns in the other two tables can have spatial indices, but I think they need to be SRID-restricted. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-index-optimization.html

Comment: It seems strange to do a right and left join together in a query. Since you want `table_1` as the reference anyway, why not just `table_1` left join with the other two tables?

Comment: @FanoFN does that make a difference? the reason why I wanted to do a left and right join was because at first `table_1` is on the right side and then it is on the left side. I just figured this would work but how would I do a left join on both those tables in a single query?

Comment: @nnichols I agree but the ST_POINT works. I don't need to create a point in `table_1` since the POINT function will do that automatically. If I run the query with just a right join with `table_1` and `table_2` it works exactly as predicted. When I add the third table is when I seem to come across issues.

Comment: Same as how you do right and left join but you start with `FROM table_1 LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table1.xxx=table_2.xx LEFT JOIN table_3 ON table1.xxx=table_3.xx`. There may not be a difference in terms of performance wise but I'm not sure. I have to know your exact table structure (including indexes) to try and replicate the situation.

Comment: @tareenmj Storing the point would allow for the use of a SPATIAL INDEX which may well give a significant benefit in the join performance. I have no useful experience with SPATIAL types in MySQL and do not understand how the R-tree index on a GEOMETRY type works. You have provided the row count for table_1 (158,407) but not the other two tables. The EXPLAIN output for your query would be helpful. If you are able to provide a link to a download of a sample dataset I would be interested to experiment with it.

Comment: @FanoFN thanks for the input but it seems that the same error exists. I made it so that there are just two left joins. It just gets stuck and I can't find the error.

Comment: @nnichols thanks for the input. The thing is I'm quite bound in that I can't change the database or tables within (since several people use it). I have updated the question so that all the rows are presented. I was thinking that maybe I could alter the query so that I filter BEFORE the joins are executed. That way, even though I have 158,407 rows in `table_1`, the `t1.`Code` != "TEST"` filter will remove several rows

Comment: You still haven't added the output from EXPLAIN of your query. A simple explanation of what the three tables represent and what you are trying to achieve may help.

Comment: Can you try running `SELECT Point( t1.Latitude, t1.Longitude) AS vals FROM table_1 t1 GROUP BY vals;` and tell us if there's any result(s)? Or it's just empty? Also try running this `SELECT ST_WITHIN( Point( 39.80, 39.80), t2.geometry ) FROM table_2 t2;` if there's any result(s).

Comment: And I think it's best if you can provide the table structures, you can run `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_x` and edit the result into your question. This way we can see the full table structures including any key/indexes etc.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data is primarily based on the T1 table as you originally had as a right-join.  You then commented about doing two left-joins, so I have adjusted to accommodate that.  Sorry I'm not familiar with geo-spatial functions/geometry indexes.

```
SELECT
        t1.Code,
        t1.price,
        t1.Latitude,
        t1.Longitude,
        t2.tier_name,
        t2.tier2_name,
        t3.id
    FROM 
        database_1.table_1 t1
            LEFT JOIN database_2.table_2 t2
                ON ST_WITHIN( Point( t1.Latitude, t1.Longitude), t2.geometry )

            LEFT JOIN database_2.table_3 t3
                ON ST_WITHIN( Point( t1.Latitude, t1.Longitude), t3.geometry )

    WHERE
        t1.Code != "TEST"
```

Comment: thanks so much for the help on my question. I did try running the query but it seems that like my original attempt, it gets stuck (since table_1 has 150,000+ rows). I was hoping to maybe do the filter `t1.code!="TEST"` PRIOR to the two joins, since that would make it more efficient.